# RxJS - multiple subscribers not executed using behaviour subject + share

Tags: rxjs

Example:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(123);
const obs = subject.asObservable().pipe(share());

obs.subscribe(console.log);

obs.subscribe(console.log);

obs.subscribe(console.log);

obs.subscribe(console.log);
```

I'm getting only one console log, but if i'll change it to shareReplay it will invoke all the subscriptions.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-simpleexample-tr3fu5?file=index.ts

Comment: Can you please specify what do you want?

Comment: maybe a minimal example might be useful (stackblitz?) [mcve]

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-behaviorsubject-simpleexample?file=index.ts?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=100

Comment: your code is wrong. you subscribe after you emitted values. and BehaviorSubject stores only the last value. put the emissions `next()` after the subscribes. updated my answer but still I don't see why you cannot use directly the subject

Comment: if i remove the share it works

Comment: your answer is wrong, i need the share operator, the only thing i'm trying to understand is why without the share operator all the subscriptions are executed.

Comment: It's doesn't matter if i use the subject or convert it to observable, it's still not working properly with the share operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you convert to Observable?

a Subject is already multicasting.
what about if you simply subscribe to `subject` ?

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(123);

subject.subscribe(console.log);

subject.subscribe(console.log);

subject.subscribe(console.log);

subject.subscribe(console.log);
```

This sentence

> What is a Subject? An RxJS Subject is a special type of Observable that allows values to be multicasted to many Observers. While plain Observables are unicast (each subscribed Observer owns an independent execution of the Observable), Subjects are multicast.

come from the [official documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/subject)

**UPDATE**

This code works

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { share } from 'rxjs/operators';

const subject = new BehaviorSubject(null);

const obs = subject.asObservable().pipe(share());

//two new subscribers will get initial value => output: 123, 123
obs.subscribe(console.log);

obs.subscribe(console.log);

obs.subscribe(console.log);

obs.subscribe(console.log);

subject.next(1)
subject.next(2)
subject.next(3)
subject.next(4)
```

Comment: i want to use share, i try to make the example very simple, i'm using share because in angular i'm using async pipe multiple times on the same observable.

Comment: what is your goal ? Subjects "are" Observables. you can use async pipes also with subjects

Comment: i have template in angular that use multiple async pipe on the same observable, i don't want to create multiple subscription so i am using share.

Comment: no, because i need behaviour subject, the problem is not with the type of the subject, can you explain why in my example the console.log executed only once?

Comment: Thanks, now i understand why it work with shareReplay :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `pipe(share())`.

This code will allow you to have multiple subscribers.

```js
const bSubject = new BehaviorSubject();
const bSubjectObservable = bSubject.asObservable();

bSubjectObservable.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("BehaviorSubject subscription 1"); // will be called
});

bSubjectObservable.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("BehaviorSubject subscription 2");
});

bSubject.next(1);
```

Unlike this code:

```js
let observableSubscriber: Subscriber;
const observable = new Observable((subscriber: Subscriber) => {
  observableSubscriber = subscriber;
});

observable.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("Observable subscription 1"); // will NOT be called
});

observable.subscribe(() => {
  console.log("Observable subscription 2");
});

observableSubscriber.next(1);
```

Because in the first variant - observable is casted from BehaviorSubject which could have multiple subscribers.
So basically `.asObservable` doesn't return pure Observable type and it's misleading the developer.

Repo: https://codesandbox.io/s/behaviorsubject-asobservable-multiple-subscribers-6gznv